# No @ResponseBody returned from @ExceptionHandler in Spring boot app deployed in Tomcat

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, exceptionhandler

I have a Spring Boot web app that runs just fine from STS but shows different behavior when running in Tomcat from a WAR file.

I use Thymeleaf to handle all my web pages but I have a couple pages that are using jQuery to send async calls and make user experience more dynamic.

Anyway, I have a Controller method that calls a service method which may throw a `RuntimeException` which I handle this way :

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyRuntimeException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody String handleMyRuntimeException(MyRuntimeException exception) {
    return "Oops an error happened : " + exception.getMessage();
}
```

In JS, I use the response body I return above to display a message on screen.

That works perfectly fine when running my app in STS but once I switch to deploy it in Tomcat the `ErrorPageFilter` gets invoked and in `doFilter()` it does:

```
if (status >= 400) {
    handleErrorStatus(request, response, status, wrapped.getMessage());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

In `handleErrorStatus()` it creates an error with the status and associated message but doesn't return my response.

I haven't figured out how to solve this and I'd really appreciate if anybody could help.

Thanks!

Comment: For now, my workaround is to catch the Exception thrown by my service and return a JSON object with a SUCCESS or FAILURE status and corresponding message and / or result data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went around this issue (I would think that is a Spring Boot issue) by doing the following.

1. Separate Rest and Mvc controllers
   See my question here : [Spring MVC: Get i18n message for reason in @RequestStatus on a @ExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273419/spring-mvc-get-i18n-message-for-reason-in-requeststatus-on-a-exceptionhandler/29294909#29294909)
2. Inject Jackson converter and write response myself :

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
   @Priority(1)
   @ResponseBody
   public class RestControllerAdvice {
       @Autowired
       private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

       @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
       @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
       public void handleRuntimeException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, RuntimeException exception) {
           try {
               jacksonMessageConverter.write(new MyRestResult(translateMessage(exception)), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, new ServletServerHttpResponse(response));
               response.flushBuffer(); // Flush to commit the response
               } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It is important to call the flushBuffer() method or this won't work.

Comment: What has really made a difference is that you've removed @ResponseStatus (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8251). Instead you can simply return a ResponseEntity. There is no need to write yourself through Jackson.

Comment: I'll try that thanks ! But if if I return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST in my ResponseEntity, wouldn't I get the same behavior ?

Comment: Returning a new ResponseEntity<MyRestResult>(myRestResult, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) produces the same result. I'll log a Boot issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @DamienPolegato Thanks so much for your code. My `@RestControllerAdvice` annotated global exception-handler would correctly pass a `ResponseEntity` to the client as JSON, but it wouldn't pass it to client on a handler for `@ExceptionHandler(value = ConstraintViolationException.class)`. You're solution let's me give a personlized Repsonse for constraints back to the client.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with a ResponseEntity, but simply writing the response directly to HttpServletResponse made it work. So thanks for that.