# Spring MVC: Get i18n message for reason in @RequestStatus on a @ExceptionHandler

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, exception, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot app with Thymeleaf mixing normal Controller calls that fetch views and REST async calls. For error handling in REST async calls, I would like to be able to provide a property as reason in exception handling and have it translated automatically by a MessageSource.

My handler is as follow.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "general.unexpected.exception")
public ModelAndView handleUnexpectedException(Exception exception) {
    logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
    return createModelAndView("error"); 
}
```

When an error occurs as part of a normal controller call, the error view is displayed. But in case of Javascript REST calls I would like to be able to have the `general.unexpected.exception` reason replaced by the corresponding text based on the user locale for example "An unexpected error happened" so I can display that in UI in my javascript fail() method in case of unhandled error.

Any clue on how to do that would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put exception handlers into classes annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, you can configure this advice to match particular controllers by specifying `annotation` attribute.

In your case, simply create separate advices for `@Controller` and `@RestController` and exception handlers with different logic for each:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
class RestAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler
    ...
}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
class MvcAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler
    ...
}
```

Comment: At this point I have few rest calls so I was looking for a way to avoid having separated controllers but I guess that's an easy and safe way to go. Also I it will make better conventions. Will see what else I can do and if no better solution i'll go with that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I went with Maciej answer but there are some additional things I had to do.
First, I had to set priority 1 to this `@ControllerAdvice` to avoid exceptions to be picked up by the other one (since `RestController` extends `Controller`).
Second, I had to annotate it `@ResponseBody` to make sure the return value of my handler would be returned as a REST response.

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
@Priority(1)
@ResponseBody
public class RestControllerAdvice {}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
@Priority(2)
public class MvcControllerAdvice {}
```